# Kali Linux - MacBook Pro no Ethernet card installed

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, network-interface, macintosh

So basically when installing Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro (single boot setup) I saw that it said no Ethernet card was found. I just clicked "don't use" as I assumed I could setup wireless later. Well now it's later. My Mac doesn't have an Ethernet cable, and in confused how I can get my MacBook to recognize my wireless card, so I can use a wireless connection. All help appreciated.

Comment: @BLayer how is this a duplicate of that? That's someone complaining about the installation process, I already set mine up perfectly except for one thing...

Comment: The answer to that is in the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/213782

Comment: Have you checked that Linux supports your hardware, and that the correct kernel modules have been included? (Remember that there are several computers called "MacBook Pro".) If your wireless hardware is not well-supported, a USB wireless or Ethernet adapter is easy to obtain